bash: keep output from 1st command while calling second command
I have a bash script that executes my_command_1 and then I do 2 things when certain stdout lines are found from that command. First, I need to figure out an ID, and then use that ID for the second command my_command_2.
command_output="my_command_1 --arg"
while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line == "str_1"*"str_2" ]]; then
     my_id="${line:20:30}"
     echo "my id: $my_id"
     echo "$line"
  elif [[ $line == *"issue command str"* ]]; then
      echo "$line"
      new_command="my_command_2 --id $my_id"
      echo "bash issuing command $new_command"
      nohup $new_command &
  else
    echo "$line"
  fi
done < <(eval "$command_output")

my_command_3 --arg

The issue: I have the script working correctly but as soon as my_command_2 is issued, the script breaks out of the while loop, at least that's what I think is happening because I don't see the stdout from my_command_1 anymore. I want the script to finish my_command_1 to completion before the last command at the bottom, my_command_3 is executed.

What are the real commands? It sounds like my_command_2 reads from standard input, so it's reading the rest of the output of my_command_1. Does it use ssh?

hmm no ssh commands. but the executable is an npm package.

Try adding redirection around it: nohup $new_command </dev/null &

ah that seems to work. I thought nohup redirecting the output took care of it since I used to see nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'. But with this redirect </dev/null i'm seeing the full output from my_command_1. Thank you @Barmar!

That's output not input.

There's more wrong with your script than the question you asked about. Please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050, why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice and learn to use http://shellcheck.net.
